# Power Query Conditional Dynamic Filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a Power Query query that uses a secondary function query that pulls parameters from a table in my workbook.  For example, to filter by date range, I use

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [EventDatetime] >= fnGetParameterValue("EventStartDate") and [EventDatetime] <= fnGetParameterValue("EventEndDate"))
```

What I'd like to do is filter only if a value returned by fnGetParameterValue("AccountNumber") is not an empty string.

I tried inserting this step after the date filter step:

```
#"Filtered Rows1" = if fnGetParameterValue("AccountNumber") = "" then #"Filtered Rows" else Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [AccountNumber] = fnGetParameterValue("AccountNumber"))
```

I don't appear to have a syntax error, but I'm not getting any data back.

How can I conditionally filter data?

Answer (score 0):

I would add an intermediate Step to Add a Column using your function (e.g. [AccountNumber Filter] ) and using your if logic, along the lines of:

`if fnGetParameterValue("AccountNumber") = "" then [AccountNumber] else fnGetParameterValue("AccountNumber")`

Then I would use that new column in a the Filter step, e.g.

`[AccountNumber] = [AccountNumber Filter]`

The intermediate step will also be clearer for review/testing etc.